# How to find out the password to a .p12 document made in openssl?

Tags: flash, openssl, certificate, iphone-developer-program, pkcs#12

I'm trying to publish an iPhone game and I have downloaded everything I need to allow me to publish through flash.  I'm on a pc and I can't figure out what the password is of the .p12 certificate I made in openssl is.  Here are the steps I've used:

I create my key:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048
```

I create a CSR with the correct info

```
openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest  -subj "/emailAddress=yourAddress@example.com, CN=John Doe, C=US"
```

I upload this to apple and then download the certificate they send me, which I convert to a PEM with this code:

```
openssl x509 -in developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM
```

For my final step, I generate the .p12 using this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

Flash requires I enter the .p12, the .p12 password, and the provisioning profile I got from apple.  I have no idea what the password is.  I'm very new to openssl so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Here's a link to the tutorial I used if you want any more info:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-19aa73f128cc9f05e8-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f46768d8712cd1d13954-7ffd

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 3):

You do not *find out* the password of a PKCS#12 file which you create. It's you who sets the password when creating the file. You can use the `-passout` flag for that. Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12 -passout pass:secret
```

This will set the password to `secret`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally that    openssl pkcs12 --export prompts for a password.  If not, then the PKCS12 file has a blank/no password. You can pass a password on the commandline if Flash is requiring one and the commandline isn't prompting you.

Comment: What do you mean by pass a password?  Sorry like I said I'm new.  And I keep on getting a "unable to write 'random state'" error when I try to make my private key and make the .p12.  It still generates a .p12 though.

Comment: it did ask me for password and then for to verify password.